# Loading, listing, and using R Modules and Functions in PL/R

Tags: postgresql, r, plr

I am having difficulty with:

- Listing the R packages and functions available to PostgreSQL.
- Installing a package (such as [Kendall](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/Kendall/html/Kendall.html)) for use with PL/R
- Calling an R function within PostgreSQL

#### Listing Available R Packages

**Q.1.** How do you find out what R modules have been loaded?

```
SELECT * FROM r_typenames();
```

That shows the types that are available, but what about checking if `Kendall( X, Y )` is loaded? For example, the [documentation](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/doc/plr-module-funcs.html) shows:

```
CREATE TABLE plr_modules (
  modseq int4,
  modsrc text
);
```

That seems to allow inserting records to dictate that `Kendall` is to be loaded, but the following code doesn't explain, syntactically, how to ensure that it gets loaded:

```
INSERT INTO plr_modules
  VALUES (0, 'pg.test.module.load <-function(msg) {print(msg)}');
```

**Q.2.** What would the above line look like if you were trying to load `Kendall`?
**Q.3.** Is it applicable?

#### Installing R Packages

Using the "synaptic" package manager the following packages have been installed:

```
r-base
r-base-core
r-base-dev
r-base-html
r-base-latex
r-cran-acepack
r-cran-boot
r-cran-car
r-cran-chron
r-cran-cluster
r-cran-codetools
r-cran-design
r-cran-foreign
r-cran-hmisc
r-cran-kernsmooth
r-cran-lattice
r-cran-matrix
r-cran-mgcv
r-cran-nlme
r-cran-quadprog
r-cran-robustbase
r-cran-rpart
r-cran-survival
r-cran-vr
r-recommended
```

**Q.4.** How do I know if Kendall is in there?
**Q.5.** If it isn't, how do I find out what package it is in?
**Q.6.** If it isn't in a package suitable for installing with `apt-get` (`aptitude`, `synaptic`, `dpkg`, what have you), how do I go about installing it on Ubuntu?
**Q.7.** Where are the installation steps documented?

#### Calling R Functions

I have the following code:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT '
  'regr_slope( amount, year_taken ),'
  'regr_intercept( amount, year_taken ),'
  'corr( amount, year_taken ),'
  'sum( measurements ) AS total_measurements '
'FROM temp_regression'
INTO STRICT slope, intercept, correlation, total_measurements;
```

This code calls the PostgreSQL function `corr` to calculate Pearson's correlation over the data. Ideally, I'd like to do the following (by switching `corr` for `plr_kendall`):

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT '
  'regr_slope( amount, year_taken ),'
  'regr_intercept( amount, year_taken ),'
  'plr_kendall( amount, year_taken ),'
  'sum( measurements ) AS total_measurements '
'FROM temp_regression'
INTO STRICT slope, intercept, correlation, total_measurements;
```

**Q.8.** Do I have to write `plr_kendall` myself?
**Q.9.** Where can I find a *simple* example that walks through:

1. Loading an R module into PG.
2. Writing a PG wrapper for the desired R function.
3. Calling the PG wrapper from a SELECT.

For example, would the last two steps look like:

```
create or replace function plr_kendall( _float8, _float8 ) returns float as '
  agg_kendall(arg1, arg2)
' language 'plr';

CREATE AGGREGATE agg_kendall (
  sfunc = plr_array_accum,
  basetype = float8, -- ???
  stype = _float8, -- ???
  finalfunc = plr_kendall
);
```

And then the `SELECT` as above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Overview

These steps list how to call an R function from PostgreSQL using PL/R.

#### Prerequisties

You must already have PostgreSQL, R, and PL/R installed.

#### Steps

1. Find R Module name (e.g., `Kendall`)
2. Change to the database user:
   `sudo su - postgres`
3. Run R
   `R`
4. Install R Module (accept `$HOME/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.9/`):
   `install.packages("Kendall", dependencies = TRUE)`
5. Choose a CRAN Mirror, when prompted.
6. Create the following table:
   `CREATE TABLE plr_modules (
   modseq int4,
   modsrc text
   );`
7. Insert into that table the directive to load the R Module in question:
   `INSERT INTO plr_modules
   VALUES (0, 'library(Kendall)' );`
8. Restart the database (or `SELECT * FROM reload_plr_modules();`):
   `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 restart`
9. Create a wrapper function in PostgreSQL:
   `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION climate.plr_corr_kendall(
   double precision[],
   double precision[] )
   RETURNS double precision AS
   $BODY$
   Kendall(arg1, arg2)
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE 'plr' VOLATILE STRICT;`
10. Create a function that uses the wrapper function.
11. Test the new function.

#### Wrapper Function

This function performs the work of gathering data from the database and creating two arrays. These arrays are passed into the `plr_corr_kendall` wrapper function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION climate.analysis_vector()
RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  v_year_taken double precision[];
  v_amount double precision[];
  i RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (
  SELECT
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken) AS year_taken,
    avg( m.amount ) AS amount
  FROM
    climate.city c,
    climate.station s,
    climate.station_category sc,
    climate.measurement m
  WHERE 
    c.id = 5148 AND 
    earth_distance( 
      ll_to_earth(c.latitude_decimal,c.longitude_decimal), 
      ll_to_earth(s.latitude_decimal,s.longitude_decimal)) <= 30 AND 
    s.elevation BETWEEN 0  AND  3000  AND 
    s.applicable AND 
    sc.station_id = s.id AND 
    sc.category_id = 1 AND 
    extract(YEAR FROM sc.taken_start) >= 1900 AND 
    extract(YEAR FROM sc.taken_end) <= 2009 AND 
    m.station_id = s.id AND 
    m.taken BETWEEN sc.taken_start AND sc.taken_end AND 
    m.category_id = sc.category_id 
  GROUP BY 
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken)
  ORDER BY
    extract(YEAR FROM m.taken)
  ) LOOP
    SELECT array_append( v_year_taken, i.year_taken ) INTO v_year_taken;
    SELECT array_append( v_amount, i.amount::double precision ) INTO v_amount;
  END LOOP;

  RAISE NOTICE '%', v_year_taken;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', v_amount;

  RETURN climate.plr_corr_kendall( v_year_taken, v_amount );
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

#### Test

Test the function as follows:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  climate.analysis_vector();
```

#### Result

A number: -0.0578900910913944